# how to edit data using php PDO

Tags: php

hye i have a little problem about editing data

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in D:\Xampp\htdocs\HomeComfort\order-edit.php:25 Stack trace: #0 D:\Xampp\htdocs\HomeComfort\order-edit.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Xampp\htdocs\HomeComfort\order-edit.php on line 25

This is an error that occur when i edit the data

```
    if (isset ($_POST['item']) ) {
  $item = $_POST['item'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $sql = 'UPDATE `order` SET `order_status`=:status WHERE `order_id`=:id';
  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  if ($statement->execute([':id' => $id,':item' => $item,':date' => $date, ':address' => $address, ':price' => $price, ':status' => $status])) {
    header("Location: admin-order.php");
  }
}
```

The error occur at line `if($statement-> execute...`after i submit after edit the data the error occur and i dont understand why

Comment: You're passing in 6 values, but have only two placeholders in your query…!?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. Your statement only specified 2 variables, yet you're trying to bind 6.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 6 parameters, but you are referencing 2 in your query, they need to completely match. You can solve this by changing this:

```
if ($statement->execute([':id' => $id,':item' => $item,':date' => $date, ':address' => $address, ':price' => $price, ':status' => $status]))
```

to

```
if ($statement->execute([':id' => $id, ':status' => $status]))
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset ($_POST['item']) ) {
  $item = $_POST['item'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $sql = 'UPDATE `order` SET `order_status`=? WHERE `order_id`= ?';
  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  if ($statement->execute([$status,$id]) {
    header("Location: admin-order.php");
  }
```